# Is there a use for a READ COMMITTED READ ONLY transaction?

Tags: postgresql

A READ COMMITTED (the default isolation level) transaction will acquire a new snapshot for each query. In a READ ONLY transaction, could you not just omit the transaction entirely and have no real difference in behaviour?

You can't use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in a read-only transaction, but you can use LOCK [TABLE], which would last until unlocked or the transaction ends. So there's one difference. Are there other differences?

Answer (score 4):

Let's suppose some queries use `now()` or one of these functions:

```
CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_TIME
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
CURRENT_TIME(precision)
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(precision)
LOCALTIME
LOCALTIMESTAMP
LOCALTIME(precision)
LOCALTIMESTAMP(precision)
```

As said in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> These SQL-standard functions all return values based on the start time
> of the current transaction

So when a query like `select * from table where somefield < now()` is part of a long-running transaction in read-committed mode, the result obtained can be significantly different from the results of the same query run outside of a transaction at the same exact point in time.

This is just one example, but it seems sufficient to refute the hypothesis that isolated read-only statements are not to be distinguished from statements in a read-committed read-only transaction.

Comment: That's a good point. This might not matter to everyone, but it is definitely a difference!

Answer (score 2):

There are few differences between autocommit mode and a `READ ONLY READ COMMITTED` transaction.

One is that with the transaction, you will get an error if you try to modify any data, for example by calling a function in a `SELECT` statement. That can serve as a way to make sure you really don't perform any data mpdifications.

Another reason could be that you want to set a parameter only for the duration of the transaction:

```
SET LOCAL work_mem = '1GB';
```

Such a setting is automatically reset as soon as the transaction is ended, which can be a useful device.

There may be other differences that don't come to my mind right now, but they are all subtle.

Comment: Yeah, SET LOCAL is a good difference, as well as rejecting write queries.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at these in pieces:

**In a READ ONLY transaction, could you not just omit the transaction entirely and have no real difference in behaviour?**

In the event of a single query against a database, you do not need to wrap the statement in a `BEGIN` / `COMMIT` block. If this is operating inside a stored procedure with multiple long-running queries where `READ COMMITTED` is not the default isolation level for a database, then a `BEGIN` / `COMMIT` can ensure the data being queried remains in a consistent state so that queries at the end of the operation do not conflict with the initial queries that may have been used to populate temporary tables.

**You can't use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in a read-only transaction ...**

Correct, as this is illogical. If one is simply reading data, there is no `UPDATE` required. Using this as a means to lock records at a row-level for read operations would make no sense.

**... but you can use LOCK [TABLE], which would last until unlocked or the transaction ends. So there's one difference.**

As stated in the above answer, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` locks specific rows in a table. Using `LOCK [TABLE]` locks every row in the table.

**Are there other differences?**

There are [several types of locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-lock.html), each with their own set of use cases. As an overzealous use of locks can result in a great deal of contention within a database, seriously affecting system performance for the people using the system, it may be a good idea to review the official documentation to understand the differences and — more importantly — *when* certain types of locks may be necessary.

---

Speaking from experience, read-only activities rarely need any form of locking. Only in very specific situations does it make sense. Write operations for most user-created data should be wrapped in a transaction to ensure that an error does not result in orphaned records. Table locking is used only during very specific accounting-related operations. Your use case may wildly differ, so take this last bit with a grain of salt.

Comment: `LOCK` does **not** lock any rows in the table.